# How to set a retry with Until for an ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have a pipeline on ADF with a `For Loop` activity and inside I have a `Data Flow` running a Kusto query. In this loop I am using a variable with 10 string in an array, so that my Data Flow will run based on those values as a parameter.

[image]

What is happening is, some of the runs in the loop is failing due to connection failure, and some others is working fine.

Example:

1 Succeeded
2 Succeeded
3 Failed
4 Succeeded
5 Succeeded
6 Failed
...

As image below:

[image]

How can I rerun only the failures one? I saw that is possible to do using `Until` activity maybe, but how if `For Loop` cannot be inside `Until`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set retry on the data flow activity inside the foreach. It will only retry failed runs and not the entire foreach.
[image: retry_Adf]

The Retry setting controls how many times to retry.

The Retry interval controls how long to wait between retries (in seconds).

Comment: Thank you!! I am crazy not to see that option before, I searched many times.